# Range of Integral

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

If $f(x)$ = $\frac{sinx}{1+x^{11}}$,

What is the upper limit of the absolute value of the integral of $f(x)$ where $x$ goes from $x=10$ to $x=19$?

I tried to integrate the function using the parameter approach where 11 was the parameter, but that did not help. This is just an assumption, but since the question asks the range, I assumed $f(x)$ to be a non-integrable function. To find the range of any function, we differentiate it and find the maxima and minima of the function, but the absolute value is asked. The problem is that the required integral is some constant, so I cannot possibly differentiate it. How am I supposed to go about this?

Comment: Wolframalpha gives no result

Comment: I think we need to use Integration via parts

Comment: Mathematica says the integral is $6.60455\cdot 10^{-12}$.

Comment: The book gives me the answer <$10^{-10}$, btw

Comment: Well, $10^{-12} < 10^{-10}$, right?

Comment: yes. just stating.

Comment: Over the range of interest, the value of the integrand is between $-5.63\times 10^{-12}$ and $2.97\times 10^{-13}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

\begin{align*}
\left|\int_{10}^{19}\frac{\sin x}{1+x^{11}} \, dx\right|& \leq \int_{10}^{19}\left|\frac{\sin x}{1+x^{11}}\right| \, dx\\
& = \int_{10}^{19}\frac{|\sin x|}{|1+x^{11}|} \, dx\\
& \leq  \int_{10}^{19}\frac{1}{1+x^{11}} \, dx\\
& \leq  \int_{10}^{19}\frac{1}{x^{11}} \, dx\\
& = \frac{1}{10}\left[\frac{1}{10^{10}}-\frac{1}{19^{10}}\right]\\
& \approx 9.983 \times 10^{-12}
\end{align*}